# How to convert svg logo into animation?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to convert svg into animation through css. I have tried following pattern as I found after researched on google.

```
@keyframes moveCircle {
from { /* start value */ }
to { /* end value */ }
}
```

I need same animation as in this [**video**](http://dowholding.com/task/index_v4.mp4). I am trying [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/7og0m5tf/) to convert svg logo to animation.

I would like to request kindly guide me how can I convert it. I would appreciate. Thank you so much

Comment: You may find this article useful: [CSS-TRICKS: stroke-dasharray](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/stroke-dasharray/)